# Kotlin function for compare Strings in different order

Tags: kotlin

I have an array like that:

```
val list = listOf("cat", "dog", "tac", "atc")
```

I would like to create from it a new array with strings consist of the same latter.

Result should be a new array without "dog".

Does Kotlin have function for that ? I was testing equal, compare and so on. I didn't find that.

Comment: What if the list was `listOf("cat", "tac", "dog", "god")`? Which entries should be removed then? It's clear in the case where there's a single outlier, but it sounds like what you have is a symmetric relation which is going to  cluster entries into subcollections.

Comment: i have to create list of strings consist of the same chars

Comment: Show some code what you’ve tried.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't have a function for that no - this is a puzzle you need to solve with the (much more general) tools it does provide!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to group the entries by the set or ordered list of their chars and then find the biggest group.

```kotlin
list.groupBy {
    it.toSet()
}.values.maxByOrNull {
    it.size
}
```

or

```kotlin
list.groupBy {
    it.toList().sorted()
}.values.maxByOrNull {
    it.size
}
```

The first will include strings which contain repetitions of char(s) to the resultant list e.g. "cat", "caat", "ttacccat". The second is stricter and will only allow strings with exactly the same chars (in any order).

As someone has mentioned, this will only work for inputs where the list of strings you want returned is the largest after you perform the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = listOf("cat", "dog", "tac", "atc")

val result = list
  .map { it.toCharArray().sorted().joinToString("") to it }
  .groupBy { it.first }
  .map { it.value.map { pair -> pair.second } }
  .groupBy { it.count() }
  .maxByOrNull { it.key }!!
  .value
  .flatten()   // remove this line if there is the possibility
               // of more than one result, like in:
               // "cat", "dog", "tac", "atc", "dgo", "god", "abc"

println(result)   // Output: [cat, tac, atc]
```